# Proof for combination using a specific definition

Tags: proof-writing, combinations

Suppose $n,k,\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq k \leq n $ prove using the following definition:

if n and k are integers then $\binom{n}{k}$ denotes the number of subsets that can be made by choosing k elements from a set with n elements.

to show that $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the $k$ elements to be in the subset is the same as choosing the $n-k$ elements that are not to be in the subset.

Answer (score 1):

By your definition, $\binom{n}{k}$ is defined to be the size of the set

$S_k := \{U \subseteq \mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \mid |U| = k\}$

so our goal is to show that $|S_k| = |S_{n-k}|$.

To be very stern and earnest about this, we must construct a bijection. In particular
$U \mapsto \mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \setminus U$ will do the trick.

To show that this map is surjective, let $U \in S_{n-k}$ so that $U \subseteq \mathbb{N}_{\leq n}$ has $n - k$ elements. Then $\mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \setminus U$ has $n - (n - k) = k$ elements so $\mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \setminus U \in S_k$. Since
$\mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \setminus (\mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \setminus U) = U$, this implies surjectivity.

For injectivity, assuming $\mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \setminus U = \mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \setminus U'$ we get that

$U = \mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \setminus (\mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \setminus U) = \mathbb{N}_{\leq n}  \setminus (\mathbb{N}_{\leq n} \setminus U') = U'$.

Thus, the map defined above is surjective and injective, hence bijective, so

$\binom{n}{k} = |S_k| = |S_{n-k}| = \binom{n}{n-k}$.

Answer (score 0):

If k is an integer and between 0 and 0 then it must be zero. Hence, n nCr k = n nCr 0, and n nCr n-k = n nCr n - 0 = n nCr n = 1. Therefore the two are equal.

I saw you've updated your question. Think of it like this:

I'm going on a camping trip and from my 10 friends I can select 3 to come with me. I can do this ${10 \choose 3}$ ways. Now consider this, is it not the same task if I'm choosing the friends who cannot come with me? yes it is! I can do this ${10 \choose 7}$ ways (note that 7 = 10 - 3.

Abstracting we have: If I'm going to choose 3 friends from my group of n friends, I can do this in ${n \choose k}$ ways. Or I can preform the identical operation of choosing my friends who aren't going which can be done in ${n \choose n-k}$ ways

Comment: oops, sorry, i wrote question wrong

Comment: I see, I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: I know that the two end up working out to be the exact same answer wise, im just unsure of how to prove it mathematically. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Mathematically? What do you mean by that? Algebraically? Or by thinking about it in terms of sets? The algebraic proof is really simple, just right out them out in their closed form and you'll see it instantly. Using sets, the proof is identical to the one I showed you. Good luck!